# Question on the definition of uniqueness (ODEs)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm diving into the theory of ODEs, specifically the existence of a unique solution of the linear system $\mathbf{y'} = A(t)\mathbf{y}$

Maybe I'm confused on exactly what uniqueness means, and you can help me clear it up.

If $A(t)$ is continuous $n \times n$ matrix on an interval $I$, then a unique solution $\boldsymbol{\phi(t)}$ exists for $\mathbf{y'} = A(t)\mathbf{y}$.

But at the same time, we say that this system has $n$ linearly independent solutions $\boldsymbol{\phi_1(t)}, \dots, \boldsymbol{\phi_n(t)}$ that all exist on the interval $I$.

If unique means "one and only one", isn't this a contradiction? Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uniqueness refers to the initial value problem. The IVP has a unique solution given an initial condition $y(t_0)=y_0$ for some $t_0\in I$ and $y_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Without any extra-condition, the system has infinitely many solutions.